Почему @Entity не создает таблицу в бд
пишу не так давно на java. Создал проект https://github.com/Nubiroed/Game, вроде подключил mySql бд. Аннотация @Entity, должна создавать таблицу из сущности 
(На другом проекте с spring, создается нормально, возможно дело в spring, но вроде созданием таблицы занимается не он.)
Но, таблица не создается. Ошибок нет. Получить из бд сущность(или класс, пока не силен в терминологии) с помощью 
у меня получилось, однако она тоже не обновляется автоматически(update вместо create  я использовал, результат не меняется). Вопрос: почему не создается таблица?
Заранее: я понимаю, что id в User должно быть Long, но chatGpt предложил такой пример(Long не работал так же). Также, скорее всего ошибка простейшая, но лично я не смог ее найти(я искал решение данного вопроса, в том числе на данном ресурсе).
Ide intellij idea
Появились новые ошибки, скорее всего связаны(не нашел чего - то похожего на спойлер или скрывающего текст) `апр. 06, 2024 10:46:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.0.CR1
апр. 06, 2024 10:46:44 PM org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
апр. 06, 2024 10:46:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
апр. 06, 2024 10:46:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:446)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:294)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:76)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:45)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:129)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:449)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:966)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1016)
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:45)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:129)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:449)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:101)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:966)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1016)
at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:156)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:366)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:76)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
... 12 more
`.

Вашему вопросу, кто-то поставил -1 и ушел, без объяснения причин.
Это с моей точки зрения нехорошо, поэтому попробую объяснить, хотя бы некоторые причины, я (честно говоря, давно не пользовался непосредственно Hibernate, так как сейчас без Spring'a (в java разработке) почти никуда, а Spring имеет Hibernate "под капотом" и удобнее пользоваться data-jpa, поэтому если я скажу что-то ошибочно, простите меня старика).
Итак:

В файле hibernate.cfg.xml необходимо написать маппинги для всех используемых сущностей, т.е. для класса User, это будет:

    <mapping class="model.User"></mapping>


Насколько я помню, я тоже сталкивался с проблемой подключения к mySQL при работе с Hibernate, сейчас не помню почему, но просто указание localhost, порта и название БД не работало, но сработало вот так в файле hibernate.cfg.xml:

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db_name_here>?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>


В методе main Вам необходимо написать код для подключения и выполнения транзакций, попробуйте, например так:

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(registry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();


После запуска проекта, зайдите в БД и убедитесь, что таблица User создана. Лучше делать это в режиме дебага.

А вот этот участок кода, вставляет строку в уже созданную таблицу и закрывает транзакцию
        User user  = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setEmail("23");
        user.setMail("2552");
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        sessionFactory.close();

Мне очень помогла книга: "Бауэр К., Кинг Г., Грегори Г. 'Java Persistence API
и Hibernate'", настоятельно рекомендую ее прочитать.
Вот сейчас еще припомнил, что я использовал пятый Hibernate и он почему-то  не дружил с коннектором mysql-connector-j , попробуйте в pom.xml попробовать (для 8 MySQL)
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
  </dependency>

